# Easter Eggs in Portal/Portal 2

Tags: portal-2, portal

Since Valve makes numerous games that are quite popular, I was wondering if anyone had a good resource for listing the Easter Eggs in Portal and Portal 2.  I've seen some web pages that list a couple, but I have a feeling that they are incomplete.  Has anyone compiled them all in one location?

Comment: Highly Related (if not an outright duplicate): [Hidden Areas in Portal 2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21640/hidden-areas-in-portal-2-single-player-campaign)

Comment: @Raven THANKS!  That will be of immense interest to my daughter.  :)

Comment: I believe this question is a bit broad. Maybe it should be split in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21640/hidden-areas-in-portal-2-single-player-campaign (which is already very good), and another question just for Portal 1. Maybe also another question for Portal 2 multiplayer.

Comment: @Denilson Sa, good points.  I was just hoping that someone had made a "collection" somewhere that I was unable to find.  I know there is one for all the sounds that my daughter loves to attach to her emails.

Comment: You would probably also enjoy the GlaDOS voice for TomTom. Not only is it her voice, but it also lies about direction and distance, and makes comments intended to provide an "atmosphere of extreme pessimism"

Comment: @Rory, it just so happens that I am in the market for a GPS.  As silly as it sounds, that may be the deciding factor in getting a TomTom over another brand!  :)

Comment: Excellent:-) My work here is done. http://simoncpage.co.uk/blog/2008/10/19/portals-glados-gps/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find any comprehensive lists, so try the following:

- GamesRadar - [Portal 2 Easter egg guide: 30 secrets and references you may have missed](http://www.gamesradar.com/portal-2-easter-egg-guide-30-secrets-and-references-you-may-have-missed/)
- Steam Forum - [List of easter eggs *spoilers*](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1867936)
- Easter Egg Archive - [Portal Easter Eggs](http://www.eeggs.com/tree/11616.html)

---

You can also try searching the [*Half-Life* Wikia](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) for ["Portal easter egg"](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/index.php?search=portal%20easter%20egg&fulltext=0).

**Addendum**: The site will [eventually move](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Klow/We_are_leaving) to http://combineoverwiki.net/

Comment: There's a Wiki for _everything_, isn't there?  I should have known!  Thanks.

Comment: A less sarcastic tone would be nice, as well as some actual content for if (when) the link rots

Comment: @nick-t I wasn't being sarcastic. If they had an easter egg page I would have linked to that.

Comment: -1 CyberSkull, please provide more information in your answer then just "Search for this". The search itself doesn't appear to provide any useful results, which hurts this answer further. As was also pointed out by @NickT, providing nothing more then a link is also problematic.  Not only does it force the user to go to another site, but if the link rots the question become useless. If you address my concerns, I would be happy to remove my -1.

Comment: The idea is to answer, not just "Search for this"